# PIL: AttributeError: close

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have the following code:

```
img = Image.open("some-file.gif".convert('RGB')
img.save('saved-file.jpg', 'jpeg')
img.close()
```

It runs perfect on local machine, but on the server it raises following exception:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 528, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: close
```

I'm using the same PIL version, but why is close() method not defined?

Comment: hmm, I feel like something is confusing here. Python says "Attribute"... and you say method?

Comment: Yes it is. If I comment out img.close() all seems to be ok. But why it doesn't work on server.

Comment: something must be different on the server side . You'll need to probably check configuration files

Comment: are you 100% sure you're using the same version of PIL? I'm looking at the documentation for [PIL](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) and [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.close) and only the latter mentions a `close` method. If you were using Pillow and the server was using PIL, this would explain the error.

Comment: There's a missing `)` in your `open` call. Please make sure the code in your question matches the code you're running.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug with Pillow 2.4.x or older (Image#close() was introduced after Pillow 2.5.0).

Reference: [blockdiag/issues](https://bitbucket.org/blockdiag/blockdiag/issues/63/attributeerror-close)